# Combination problem approach when at least one of one type must be included

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Question:In how many ways can 6 be chosen from 4 officers and 8 privates to include at least 1 officer?

The correct answer is to consider all the cases in which at least 1 officer is chosen and then add them together.

- 1 officer + 5 private
- 2 officer + 4 private
- 3 officer + 3 private
- 4 officer + 2 private

But what is wrong with the following approach (it gives wrong answer)

1 officer out of 4 can be chosen in $^4C_1$ ways and remaining 5 people out of 11 can be chosen in $^{11}C_5$ ways, so the total number of ways of selecting 6 people in which at least 1 officer is present = $^4C_1 * ^{11}C_5$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Question:In how many ways can 6 be chosen from 4 officers and 8 privates to include at least 1 officer?

The easiest way is to count the total and subtract the complement.

(Count of those with At Least 1 Officer) = (Count of All Combinations) - (Count those with No Officers)

$$\,^{12}C_6 - \,^{8}C_6 = 896$$

This will give the same answer as summing all the ways.

$$\,^{4}C_1 \,^{8}C_5 + \,^{4}C_2 \,^{8}C_4 + \,^{4}C_3 \,^{8}C_3 + \,^{4}C_4 \,^{8}C_2 = 896$$

---

$\,^4C_1 \,^{11}C_5$ is the way to select 1 officer as *leader* of a team of 6 when the rest of the team can be filled by either officers or privates.   When the first officer selected does *not* have a distinct placement, you run into double counting issues.

You're counting the ways to select officer 1 to 4 and, for each one, counting the ways to fill the rest of the team, including those with the remaining officers. But it doesn't matter if you select officer 1 first and officer 2 among the rest, or officer 2 first and officer 1 among the rest.  Those are the same combinations.